# SQL temp table to point to real table - using SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, archive, sql-server-2014

I am working on archiving data in my database being that it's getting really heavy and slowing down the server.

I have a script running automatically every day to move that day's data to a file.

All my existing selects must change now. Instead of selecting from the regular table it could be either the archived file or the regular one. I don't want to have a variable name defining which table to select from because then all my existing stored procedures must turn into dynamic SQL.

So I was going to have a temp table that gets filled either with my archived data or with my current data from the current table. And then I would select from the temp table.

The problem is that if it's the current I don't want to have to select from that table to put it into a temp table. It's a heavy table and I could only select from it with where clauses. Since my stored procedure uses the table multiple times with different where clauses I would have to dump the whole table into my temp table. This is affecting the wait time for the customer.

I thought maybe to have the temp table just pointing to the real table instead of selecting from it.

Is this possible in SQL Server 2014?

If not any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at using a [view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or a [partitioned table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190787%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)?

Comment: I can create a view dynamically with the data that I need but then if there are 2 users accessing the data with different parameters for the querying it won;t reflect those parameters.

Comment: How many records are in the main table at peak time?

Comment: Could be 100s of thousands

Comment: If that's the amount of data, I believe it should be possible to optimize it to the customer's satisfaction. SQL Server can handle billions of rows with good performance. I believe that with the right optimization, you can make a both simpler and faster setup at the same time. If you could provide more information about your schema: Tables, indexes, queries, that would be helpful.

Comment: would synonyms help at all? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187552.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: A synonym is a great idea and really would help me, however there is one major pitfall.  The base object of the synonym can change per query per user.  If there is a concept of a temporary synonym that would be exactly what I need.  Do you have any ideas for me?